# how to copy the console output of this program in java

Tags: java

```
package prgms;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class new_experi
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Abhilasha      U//Desktop//output.txt"));
  try 
    { 
      Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir"); 
      p.waitFor(); 
      BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
      ); 
      String line; 
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      { 
          System.out.println(line);
      }  
    }
    catch(IOException e1) {} 
      System.out.println("Done");  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple.

```
package prgms;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class new_experi
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Abhilasha      U//Desktop//output.txt"));
  try 
    { 
      Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir"); 
      p.waitFor(); 
      BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
      ); 
      String line; 
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      { 
          System.out.println(line);
      }  
    }
    catch(IOException e1) {} 
      System.out.println("Done");  
// This will pause your application so that you can take a screen shot !!
   System.in.read();
}
}
```

If you are running this on an IDE, compile this program and run it. Once it is seen in the console. Press Alt + Print screen button then it will print screen your console.